# How to display all the record by date wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Table

```
PersonID Date 

001 11-02-2009
002 11-02-2009
003 11-02-2009
001 12-02-2009
004 12-02-2009
005 12-02-2009
003 13-02-2009
005 13-02-2009
```

So on…,

I want to display all the Personid by Date wise.

Expected Output

```
PersonID Date

001 11-02-2009
002 11-02-2009
003 11-02-2009
004 11-02-2009
005 11-02-2009
001 12-02-2009
002 12-02-2009
003 12-02-2009
004 12-02-2009
005 12-02-2009
001 13-02-2009
002 13-02-2009
003 13-02-2009
004 13-02-2009
005 13-02-2009
```

So on…,

All the Personid should appear by date wise.

I wrote a query in Access

Query

```
SELECT AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId FROM ((SELECT p.PersonId, AllDates.CardEventDate FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM TMP_Cardevent2) AllDates, Tmp_cardevent1  p) AllPossibleCardEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_cardevent2  Actual ON AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId = Actual.PersonId AND AllPossibleCardEvents.Date = Actual.Date) )
```

Above Access Query is Working Fine. But the same result I want to show in SQL also.

How to write a query in SQL?

Need Query Help.

Comment: The query is a bit complex to understand, and perhaps SQL has a much human readable way to get those results (perhaps!) .. can you provide information about the tables?

Comment: Above query - PersonID is displaying for all the dates.

Comment: Where id = 005 date = 11-02-2009 come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.PersonID, B.Date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PersonID from myTable) A, 
(SELECT DISTINCT Date from myTable) B
```

I have not tried this. But, it will do a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want every distinct personid returned for every distinct date.

If so the query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonTable.PersonId, DateTable.Date FROM Table as PersonTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM Table) AS DateTable
```